# Error When Trying to Click on an `a` Tag - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I have a very simple program that opens https://google.com and clicks on the first link. I have used `WebDriverWait` to make sure the element is ready to be clicked, though it still doesn't work, and outputs and error.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
import time

wd = webdriver.Firefox()

wd.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=python")

# wd.find_element_by_css_selector("a").click()  # This doesn't work, same error
WebDriverWait(wd, 1000000).until(
    expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a"))
).click()

time.sleep(5)

wd.close()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ketha\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Youngwonks\InteractingWithWebsites\selenium_basics.py", line 17, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(wd, 1000000).until(
  File "C:\Users\ketha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\ketha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\ketha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ketha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <a class="gyPpGe"> could not be scrolled into view
```

I am using Firefox.
Firefox Version: 89.0 (64 bit)
Selenium Version: 3.141.0
Geckodriver Version: 0.29.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong locator.
Definitely not all the `a` elements are links, especially the first `a` on that page.
Try using this instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
import time

wd = webdriver.Firefox()

wd.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=python")

# wd.find_element_by_css_selector("a").click()  # This doesn't work, same error
WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(
    expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='search']//a[contains(@href,'http')]"))
).click()

time.sleep(5)

wd.close()
```

Also, no need to define such a long timeouts for the explicit wait. 20-30 seconds are enough in most cases.